# Drawing the 2.4Ghz ISM band using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to make the figure below in Tikz.
However, since I am relatively new to Tikz I cannot make an image myself without example code. I haven't seen another person asking for something similiar, so I am a little bit clueless at the moment.

[image: 2.4 Ghz ISM band]

Is there anyone that can help me drawing this 2.4 Ghz ISM band using Tikz?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Visit http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ for examples.

Comment: @nidhin Thank you for your response. I checked the categories computer science, physics and mathematics, but there was no example that is similiar to the 2.4 Ghz ISM band.

Comment: @HenriMenke I have read the Tikz and PGF manual trying to find something similiar that I can work on. There is a one-liner to plot a function, but I am not too experienced to work with it.

Comment: @Xhendos The first 150 pages or so of the TikZ manual are tutorials.  Have you worked through them?  Afterwards it should be a piece of cake to draw what you want.

Comment: Drawing the picture is almost trivial. What probably prevents many to just post a solution is that from what you are telling us it is not clear how the pattern of numbers emerges. Why are 37 and 38 special? How are the frequencies determined?

Comment: @marmot The numbers 37, 38 and 39 are special because they are the advertising channels according to the Bluetooth low energy specifications. They are positioned right there to avoid the channels that Wi-Fi are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To give you a start (and to show it is really simple, even marmots can do that ;-).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90,transform shape]
\xdef\lstN{37}
\foreach \X in {0,...,36}
{\xdef\lstN{\lstN,\X}
\ifnum\X=10
\xdef\lstN{\lstN,38}
\fi}
\xdef\lstN{\lstN,39}
\foreach \X [count=\Y,evaluate=\Y as \Z using {int(2400+2*\Y)}] in \lstN
{\draw[overlay] (0,-\Y/2) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=12] coordinate[midway](aux)
(0,{-(\Y+1)/2}) coordinate (aux1);
\foreach \XX in {37,38,39}
{\ifnum\X=\XX
\fill[blue!20] (0,-\Y/2) to[out=0,in=0,looseness=12] (0,{-(\Y+1)/2});
\fi}
\node at (0.5,{-(2*\Y+1)/4}){\X};
\node[anchor=east,font=\sffamily] at (-0.1,{-(2*\Y+1)/4}){\Z\,MHz};
\path(aux); 
  }
\draw (0,-1/2) -- (aux1);  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The result is not so nice like marmot's, but I think with easier code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}
\clip (-1mm,0) rectangle (20cm,3);
\foreach \i in {1,...,40}
    \node[ellipse, shape border rotate=90, minimum width=5mm, 
    minimum height=5cm, draw, anchor=east] at (\i*5mm,0) (\i) {};
\end{scope}

\draw (1.west)--(40.east);

\foreach \i [count=\ni, evaluate=\i as \fq using int(2040+2*\i)] in {37,0,1,...,10,38,11,12,...,36,39}{
    \node at ([yshift=7mm]\ni.center) {\i};
    \node[rotate=90, anchor=east] at ([yshift=-2mm]\ni.center) {\fq\ MHz};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]